# Passing vba variable date to sql statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

As a newbie in `vba-sql`, I am trying to populate a table using a for loop in `vba` and the `Docmd.runsql` to populate the table. The code works fine but then the values in the table are: 12/30/1899 for all the records. I used a message box to check and `dt` works fine. It gives me the date in the loop and moves to the next but in the table it only gives me one date: 12/30/1899.

```
Function dateTblUpdate()

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [date-table]"
    Dim dt As Date



    For dt = #1/1/2010# To DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
       'MsgBox DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
       'MsgBox dt
        DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert into [date-table] (the_date) values(" & dt & ")"

   Next
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Function
```

### date-table current outcome

```
the_date
----------
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
```

But Expected outcome:

```
the_date
------------
01/01/2010
01/02/2010
01/03/2010
01/04/2010
```

My date column is of date type and I believe sql is thinking dt is not a date so it is not saving it and saving the default date.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `#` characters before and after your literal date value.  Otherwise the db engine will interpret something like *26/5/2015* as 26 divided by 5 divided by 2015 ... IOW as a math expression, not the date you intended.

```vb
"Insert into [date-table] (the_date) values(" & Format(dt, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & ")"
```

However if you use a parameter query, you wouldn't need to bother about those `#` characters in the SQL statement:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim dt As Date
Dim strInsert As String

strInsert = "INSERT INTO [date-table] (the_date) VALUES (pDate)"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)

'For dt = #1/1/2010# To DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
For dt = #1/1/2010# To Date
    qdf.Parameters("pDate").Value = dt
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Next
```

Note using the `QueryDef.Execute` method removes the motivation for `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`.  Turning `SetWarnings` off suppresses information, including information which could be useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: how did I know you will come up with a fancy answer. I always look forward to your answers. You are knowledgeable #respect

Comment: ++ parameterized queries FTW

Answer (score 2):

Since the SQL you're building is:

```
Insert into [date-table] (the_date) values(1/1/2010)
```

The interpreter may be doing integer division and saving a `0` value, which is the default date.  Enclose the value in pound signs instead:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert into [date-table] (the_date) values(#" & dt & "#)"
```

Comment: No, it will fail in a non-US environment. dt must be formatted to a string expression: Format(dt, "yyyy\/mm\dd").